# Obtaining incorrect result while performing left outer join using Linq-Why?

Tags: c#, linq, left-join

I have the below

```
public class Person
    { 
        // Properties
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Area { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public List<Person> GetPersonData()
        {
            List<Person> personLst = new List<Person>  {
           new Person { Name="Shashidhar Niketani", Age=20, Gender="Male" , Area = "Assam"},
           new Person { Name="Ahmed Ali Khan", Age=25 ,Gender="Male", Area = "Assam" },
           new Person { Name="S. Mirja", Age=20, Gender="Female", Area = "Assam"},
           new Person { Name="Neru Kumar", Age=18, Gender="Female", Area = "Colombo"},
           new Person { Name="Chidam P", Age=19, Gender="Male", Area = "Colombo"},
           new Person { Name="H Kontala", Age=19, Gender="Male", Area = "Bombay"},
           new Person { Name="Priya Pankhraj", Age=23, Gender="Female", Area = "North Punjab"},
             new Person { Name="Ambla", Age=20, Gender="Female", Area = "Madras"},
           new Person { Name="H Kontala", Age=25, Gender="Male", Area = "Bombay"},
           new Person { Name="Sirisha Chalukuri", Age=30, Gender="Female", Area = "Bombay"}};
            return personLst;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Patient Name: =  {0} , Age:= {1}, Gender:= {2}, Area: = {3}", Name, Age, Gender, Area);
        }

    }

    public class Hobbies
    {
        public string Owner { get; set; }
        public string HobbyName { get; set; }

        public List<Hobbies> GetHobbies()
        {
            List<Hobbies> hobbyList = new List<Hobbies>  {
           new Hobbies { Owner="Sirisha Chalukuri", HobbyName = "Singing"},
           new Hobbies { Owner="Priya Pankhraj", HobbyName = "Cooking" },
           new Hobbies { Owner="S. Mirja", HobbyName="Playing"},
           new Hobbies { Owner="Neru Kumar", HobbyName="Programing"}};
           return hobbyList;
        }
    }
```

I am trying to perfom a left join

//fetch those records

```
Person p = new Person();
var personSource = p.GetPersonData();

Hobbies h = new Hobbies();
var hobbySource = h.GetHobbies();
```

//Left outer join

```
var res8 = (from person in personSource                       
                        join hobby in hobbySource
                        on p.Name equals hobby.Owner into temp
                        from hobby in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new
                            {
                                PersonName = p.Name,
                                PersonAge = p.Age,
                                Gender = p.Gender,
                                LivesIn = p.Area,
                                Hobby = (hobby == null) ? "N/A" : hobby.HobbyName
                            });
```

But I am not able to get the correct result...All the records are coming as null/non matching records..There are atleast 4 matching records and the rest will be non-matching records...

I am rather looking for like given these two datasource, the result that we will expect if we perform a left join on PersonName and HobbyOwner.

Help needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reference hobby.HobbyName in your select projection, hobby is null when there are no matching hobbies for a person (DefaultIfEmpty returns null for an empty hobby collection). You need to check if hobby is null, and if so assign the Hobby property in the select projection a default value. For example:

```
select new
{
  PersonName = p.Name,
  PersonAge = p.Age,
  Gender = p.Gender,
  LivesIn = p.Area,
  Hobby = (hobby == null) ? "N/A" : hobby.HobbyName
});
```

Also, don't know if it was a typo, but in your query you use p when you should be using person:

```
var res8 = (from person in personSource                       
        join hobby in hobbySource
        on person.Name equals hobby.Owner into temp
        from hobby in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new
        {
         PersonName = person.Name,
         PersonAge = person.Age,
         Gender = person.Gender,
         LivesIn = person.Area,
         Hobby = (hobby == null) ? "N/A" : hobby.HobbyName
         });
```

Comment: Ok now the error has gone away..but i am not getting the correct result..There are atleast 4 matching records but all are coming as null records...please help with the query too

Answer (score 0):

By definition a left outer join will fetch all records from the first collection irrespective of whether a matching record exists in the right collection or not.

I think what you are looking for is:

```
var res8 = (from person in personSource                       
                        join hobby in hobbySource
                        on p.Name equals hobby.Owner into temp
                        from hobby in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new
                            {
                                PersonName = p.Name,
                                PersonAge = p.Age,
                                Gender = p.Gender,
                                LivesIn = p.Area,
                                Hobby = hobby == null ? null : hobby.HobbyName
                            });
```

Comment: Ok now the error has gone away..but i am not getting the correct result..There are atleast 4 matching records but all are coming as null records...please help with the query too

Comment: As @thedugas and @DarkTygur have correctly pointed out, the query should use `person` instead of `p`

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I needed to do with your code to make it work is change every occurrence of `p` to `person` in your last block (and only your last block, which I copied, modified, and pasted below):

```
var res8 = (from person in personSource
                    join hobby in hobbySource
                    on person.Name equals hobby.Owner into temp
                    from hobby in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new {
                        PersonName = person.Name,
                        PersonAge = person.Age,
                        Gender = person.Gender,
                        LivesIn = person.Area,
                        Hobby = (hobby == null) ? "N/A" : hobby.HobbyName
                    });
```

In addition, I don't know how similar this code is to your actual code, but your GetPersonData() and GetHobbies() functions make more sense as static methods.  That way you don't need to create a useless instance of Person or Hobbies just to get your list. It looks like that `p` Person instance up there threw you off.